# Redistributing layout space when a QWidget is hidden

Tags: c++, qt

We have a QGridLayout which has a particular row which is arranged like so:

```
+---------------------------+
|     |                |    |
|  A  |       B        |  C |
|     |                |    |
+---------------------------+
```

At times, the QWidget (a QLabel) denoted as 'B' is hidden. When this occurs, I want widgets 'A' and 'C' (two QButtons) to redistribute 50/50. Later I would like to place 'B' back in the flow and give them their 20/60/20'ish layout.

I've tried `B->hide()` `B->setVisible(false)` `layout->removeWidget(B)` but in each of these cases, 'B's space is still reserved on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your layout (since it's a « grid », all the column have to be shrinked).

Instead of putting all 3 in the GridLayout, add them to a QHBoxLayout that you add with
`gridLayout->addLayout(vLayout, 0, row, 1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have colspan 10, then A would take 2 columns, B - 6 and C - 2

you add widgets to layout like this:

```
layout->addWidget(A,0,0,1,2); // 2 - is rowspan
layout->addWidget(B,0,2,1,6); // 6 - is rowspan
layout->addWidget(C,0,8,1,2); // 2 - is rowspan
```

There: 20-60-20, but when you need only A and C with 50 by 50, you need to remove A,B,C from layout and add them again as

```
layout->addWidget(A,0,0,1,5); // 5 - is rowspan
layout->addWidget(C,0,5,1,5); // 5 - is rowspan
```